# push new array of object into existing array of object using spread of ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Is this syntax even correct? results is my array of object, it's nested.

```
notifications: {
  ...state.notifications,
  results: [
    ...state.notifications.results,
    { ...state.notifications.results }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible for that to be valid, though it looks like quite a strange thing to do

Comment: `Is this syntax even correct?` yes it is

Comment: please add the wanted result (and `state.notifications`). it is strange to spread an array in an object, you get an object with indices as keys, but if wanted, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should be work.

```
notifications: {
  ...state.notifications,
  results: [
    ...state.notifications.results
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're trying to run `this.setState`, and update your array whilst doing so.

The full command would be something like this:

```
this.setState({
  notifications: {
    ...this.state.notifications,
    results: [
      ...this.state.results,
      // whatever you're trying to add goes here
    ]
  }
});
```

I'm just guessing based upon the tags on your question. Feel free to comment and explain your situation further so I can tailor my answer to better suit your question.